# TCPView: [System Process]

Tags: windows, tcp, udp

In TCPView I get a lot of connections listed under the **Process** column as [System Process].

These connections cannot be terminated, and cannot be whoised.

How can I find out what programs started these connections and how to manipulate those programs, those connections and that data on the PC?

Version is Windows 10.

EDIT: 
Screenshot (some processes removed or anonymized):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOyY4.jpg

EDIT 2: The [System Process] connections seems to correlate with other programs that have opened connections. Why did they duplicate as [System Process]?

Comment: Some screen shots would help us understand your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: And add what version of Windows you are using.